# What is the term for an art show featuring two artists?

Tags: terminology

An art show with one artist is a solo show. One featuring many artists is called a group show. What in the generally-accepted industry term for an art show that only has two artists? A dual show? A duo show?

Comment: Two individuals can already form a group. Another word that comes to mind is 'collaboration'.

Comment: Could get more answers asking this over on [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/)....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "group exposition" or "collective exhibition" could be used to describe a two person art show ... BUT (after searching the internuts a bit) it seems that *"Duo Exhibition"* is the most common term for a two artist show. Group Exposition or Collective Exhibition applies to shows which have three artists or more.

**Examples:**

- In the [exhibition guidelines for the MacDonald Island Community Art Gallery Exhibition](http://www.macdonaldisland.ca/userfiles/files/2015%20Exhibition%20Guidelines.pdf) they list three categories of exhibitions which depends on the number of artists showing: Solo, Duo and Collective
- [SEÇİL BÜYÜKKAN gallery discussing the Seçil Büyükkan and Deniz Aktaş "Hande Şarman" show](http://www.secilbuyukkan.com/texts.asp?id=7)  refers to the event as a "Duo Exhbibition".
- The [CV for visual artist Yooree Yang](http://www.yooreeyang.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/yooreeyang_portfolio-2016.pdf) gives a listing of Solo Exhibition & "Duo Exhibitions" the artist has participated in the past

Comment: I converted the numbered list to a bulleted one as to not imply an order. I also converted some text into links to help the flow better. Nice finds.

Comment: Thx for the edit! Appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1):

I've often seen **two-person exhibition** used to describe this kind of show. A simple [web search on the term](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22two-person%20exhibition%22) brings up a number of examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think this really can depend on the artists purpose or goal. I found a Google book called [Fine Art Publicity: The Complete Guide for Galleries and Artists](https://books.google.ca/books?id=isGZxZCAPAkC&pg=PT90&lpg=PT90&dq=art+exhibition+with+multiple+artist&source=bl&ots=TSBHuFQi6O&sig=zfDO7nWYSsNuj670aW461QEPwTc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2xtnqnJ_OAhXD8YMKHan1BXwQ6AEITzAM#v=onepage&q=art%20exhibition%20with%20multiple%20artist&f=false) that talks about this. What little we can see for free that is pertinent talks about creating press release for these refers to them as **Multiple Artist and Theme Exhibitions**.

[An article discussing a (at the time) future exhibition](http://www.ago.net/ago-to-bring-giants-of-british-art-francis-bacon-and-henry-moore-together-for-major-exhibition-this-spring) featuring two artists as just that: An exhibition. The search that led me had the subject:

> Francis Bacon & Henry Moore: Terror and Beauty

One could argue that it was a themed art exhibit. In this case the two artists were from the same period, drawing on a similar war torn past into their works, but never collaborated together during their lives.

As we can see in the [other](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/a/2020/44) [answers](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/a/2022/44) there are multiple terms in use to describe this. I think the goal of the artists and hosting gallery or venue will drive what terms they would use to describe their exhibition/exhibit. I don't think there is one answer for this.